# Is webcam video stream compressed by the hardware/firmware or software driver?

Tags: video, compression, webcam

Webcams drivers offers a compressed stream (like MPEG or H.264) that can go directly to applications (like Skype, web browser, etc).

Is compression made by the driver software (operating system), or by the webcam hardware related firmware?

Answer (score 1):

Software compression is highly unlikely: while it is possible that a driver offers it, a typical driver's task is to be a think layer between hardware and OS services. You can typically monitor CPU load when video capture session is running, software compression will have to result in noticeable CPU load levels, also correlating with video resolution and frame rate.